# Meteor allow-access-control-origin

Tags: node.js, meteor, access-control, trello

I'm attempting to use the node-trello package to interact with the Trello API inside a Meteor app. However running through setup and attempting to make an api call in my client-side javascript file, I get this error.

[image: error message]

This is my code in my javascript file, following the documentation for the package.

```js
var Trello = require('node-trello');

var t = new Trello(Meteor.settings.public.trelloKey, Meteor.settings.public.trelloToken);
t.get('/1/members/me', function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

I'm not exactly sure what the error means or how to fix it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google will help you find an answer to your problem, by searching for the error message.

The problem is basically a security one, because you are making http requests from the browser to another site (Trello), and you need to let the browser know that it's ok to allow these requests by setting up some headers. I'll let you research what those are.

A better solution is for you to write a server method to do these things. The server process is not restricted in the requests to other sites that it makes, so you avoid the need to maintain headers, and you also won't hit any firewall issues (because perhaps the user's environment doesn't allow access to 3rd party services like Trello).

Comment: You could even mention the advantage of a Server side method to keep the keys private.